# Why cant I add a URL as a prefilled Wufoo field entry?

Tags: html, forms, url

I am trying to write some code that will put the current tabs URL into a wufoo form as a default value in the form hash.  The code works fine but the wufoo form doesn't want to cooperate.  instead of filling the correct URL (Say https://wufoo.com for example) it drops one of the / characters.  This also happens if you skip the code and simply type the URL hash as in the example below:

https://ownthistown.wufoo.com/forms/q1d68ngv1qovy1o/def/&field1=http://wufoo.com

The field would show https:/wufoo.com as the entry.  ANyone have any ideas why this is happening?