# How to prepopulate a wufoo field with an URL?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, wufoo

It seems that Wufoo has a bug because I cannot get to prepopulate a field of my embedded Wufoo form with an url. I am using the javascript embedding method that you can initialize with a `'defautValues'` option.

Unfortunately, if I initialize a field with an url (for example: `'defaultValues':'Field1=https://youtube.com'`), Wufoo strips 1 slash from the url which makes it invalid.

I tried "urlencoding" the url (for example: `'defaultValues':'Field1=https%3A%2F%2Fyoutube.com'`) but then wufoo produces an error and does not display the form.

Here is a sample form for you to try and see the behavior by yourself :

```html
<div id="wufoo-mrmifr316ya92y">
Fill out my <a href="https://democratech.wufoo.com/forms/mrmifr316ya92y">online form</a>.
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">var mrmifr316ya92y;(function(d, t) {
var s = d.createElement(t), options = {
'userName':'democratech',
'formHash':'mrmifr316ya92y',
'autoResize':true,
'height':'259',
'async':true,
'host':'wufoo.com',
'defaultValues':'Field1=https://youtube.com', //removes 1 slash (https:/youtube.com)
//'defaultValues':'Field1=https%3A%2F%2Fyoutube.com', //produces an error
'header':'hide',
'ssl':true};
s.src = ('https:' == d.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'www.wufoo.com/scripts/embed/form.js';
s.onload = s.onreadystatechange = function() {
var rs = this.readyState; if (rs) if (rs != 'complete') if (rs != 'loaded') return;
try { mrmifr316ya92y = new WufooForm();mrmifr316ya92y.initialize(options);mrmifr316ya92y.display(); } catch (e) {}};
var scr = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0], par = scr.parentNode; par.insertBefore(s, scr);
})(document, 'script');</script>
```

Do you confirm the bug ? Is there any workaround other than removing the `https://` from the field (which is not a very good workaround for me) ?

This question has been asked already here : [Why cant I add a URL as a prefilled Wufoo field entry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30312832/why-cant-i-add-a-url-as-a-prefilled-wufoo-field-entry) but as it was not answered, I thought I would ask a more detailed question with an example to actually try the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just received an answer from Wufoo tech support (it was fast for a Sunday question!) :

> Thanks for reaching out. Sorry to hear you're having issues with this.
>   the URL mods do work with the /, but if you put multiple together, it
>   can only display the first one. Sorry for the bad news on that one.
>   I'm afraid there's not a workaround to make that work even if you were
>   to use a different field such as a single line text field.
>
> What you could do instead is just predefine the field with
>   www.youtube.com rather than http://youtube.com. That way you can still
>   add the website, but it just wouldn't have https in it. Sorry you
>   can't do what you're wanting here. Let us know if you have any other
>   questions.
>
> Best,

So it seems this is indeed a bug and that there is no proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer but rather a workaround that can work in some cases. If you are using the wufoo webhook notification, you could post-process the "trimmed" url that the prepopulated wufoo form sends you (the one with only 1 slash) to make sure to add the second slash before saving the url in your database (or else). To do this, I am using a ruby function like the following:

```
def fix_wufoo_bug(url)
    url.gsub!(':/','://') if url.match(/https?:\/\//).nil?
    return url
end
```